# How to Resolve "Parsing error: This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): 'jsx, flow, typescript'" in Vue SFC

Tags: babeljs, eslint

I'm getting this strange error with eslint inside of a Vue SFC template.

`Parsing error: This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): 'jsx, flow, typescript' (1:0)` (Which appears to be throwing on the opening tag of the Vue SFC `<template>` tag.)

Here's the Vue SFC (literally the stock Vite `App.vue` file)

```
<template>
  <img
    alt="Vue logo"
    src="./assets/logo.png"
  >
  <HelloWorld
    msg="Hello Vue 3 + Vite"
  />
</template>
```

Here's my `.eslintrc` file

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'airbnb-base',
  ],
  parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    requireConfigFile: false,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: [
    'vue',
  ],
  rules: {
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': ['error', { devDependencies: true }],
    'vue/no-multiple-template-root': 'off',
  },
};
```

And my `package.json` in case it's relevant

```
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vite build",
    "dev": "vite",
    "lint": "eslint **/*.{js,vue}",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ky": "^0.28.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.15.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.2.3",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.5",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.17.0",
    "jest": "^27.1.0",
    "vite": "^2.3.7"
  }
}
```

I'm not really sure what would cause this since I have

```
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'airbnb-base',
  ],
```

and

```
  plugins: [
    'vue',
  ],
```

within `.eslintrc`.

I'd like to know how to resolve this, but I would also like to understand what's going on here to cause this error to be thrown in the first place.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The issue was being caused by this within `.eslintrc`

```
  parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    requireConfigFile: false,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
```

It should instead be

```
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
    requireConfigFile: false,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
```

The `parser` property isn't even mentioned within https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-parser-options so it might just be outdated at this point.